# How to rescale an int using two possibly bigger numbers in (a*X)/b formula

Tags: c, integer-arithmetic

I have a formula in c that looks like this:

```
X = (a * X) / b;
```

This is used to rescale `X` with `a/b`. However `X` is 16 bit unsigned int and multiplication with `a` could easily overflow. How could I do this calculation using just integers with an accurate result.

I could of course use floating point arithmetic, but there is a high chance this operation will work on a processor without floating point hardware.

EDIT: I forgot to say that a and b are both 32 bit unsigned integers.
Well my answer was to rightshift `a` and `b` until they both fit in 16 bits. That way `a * X` is 32 bits max and the final calculation is accurate.

Comment: Can you promote them to 32 bit and then downcast as you assign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can promote `a` to a bigger data type, for example:

```
X = ((long)a * X) / b;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite it like this:

```
X = (a/b)*X + (a%b)*(X/b) + (a%b)*(X%b)/b
```

if you can be sure any of those doesn't overflow (the first is approximately result, the second is less than result, the third dividend approx `b^2`).

Why is that valid (provided no overflows occur, / means ordinary division, div integer division):

```
X div Y =def floor(X/Y)
X =def (X div Y) * Y + X mod Y

(X*Y) div Z = floor(X*[(Y div Z) * Z + Y mod Z] / Z)
  = floor(X*(Y div Z)*Z/Z + X*(Y mod Z)/Z)
  = X*(Y div Z) + X*(Y mod Z) div Z
```

now, if we use this twice (with the C meaning of operators):

```
X = (a*X)/b = X*(a/b) + X*(a%b)/b =
            = X*(a/b) + (a%b)*(X/b) + (a%b)*(X%b)/b
```

But I would recommend computing in a bigger precision, if that's possible

```
X = ((int)X*a)/b
```

Comment: Wow, really usefull! Does this fornula has a name?

Comment: I have written a simple test that show how it works well: https://gist.github.com/jerome-pouiller/549793880c46f93960716ee01b4a4888